# Scaling a continuous feature in the test set according to the train set

Tags: r, machine-learning, scaling, r-caret

I'm building a GBM classifier to predict a certain target variable.

My data contains many continuous variables, and I want to scale only one of them (`age`) using the `scale` function. I should scale this variable in the train set and then scale it in the test set **according to the train set**, and that is so I don't get information leakage. My question is how do I apply this in R?

The way I'm doing this is by scaling the age feature separately in the train set and the test set which is not quite right. Here is my code (I use the caret package):

```
for (i in (1:10)) {
  print(i)
  set.seed(i)
  
  IND = createDataPartition(y = MYData$Target_feature, p=0.8, list = FALSE)
  TRAIN_set = MYData[IND, ]
  TEST_set = MYData[-IND,]
  
  TRAIN_set$age = scale(TRAIN_set$age)
  TEST_set$age = scale(TEST_set$age)
  
  GBMModel <- train(Target_feature~., data = TRAIN_set,
                    method = "gbm",
                    metric="ROC",
                    trControl = ctrlCV,
                    tuneGrid = gbmGRID,
                    verbose = FALSE
                    
  )
  
  
  AUCs_Trn[i] = auc(roc(TRAIN_set$Target_feature,predict(GBMModel,TRAIN_set, type='prob')[,1]))
  AUCs_Tst[i] = auc(roc(TEST_set$Target_feature,predict(GBMModel,TEST_set, type='prob')[,1]))
  
}
```

NOTE: I only want to scale the `age` feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to manually scale the test data by the mean and standard deviation from the training set (equivalent to what scale() does).

```
test$age_scaled = (test$age - mean(train$age) ) / sd(train$age)
```

Comment: was writing the same idea, but was too slow :)

Comment: Should I also use `scale(TRAIN_set$age)` before this line of code? or is this enough?

Comment: Yes, you also need to scale the training data, scale() is fine for that, or you can write it out like for the test-data `train$age = ( train$age - mean(train$age) / sd(train$age)`

Comment: @Antti but wouldn't the values of the train and the test be very different this way? I mean, after I scale the `train`, the values will be very small (with mean = 0 etc..). Now I'll use these values to scale the `test` set. So for example when I do `test$age - mean(train$age)`, the test values are still the original numbers and the mean of the `train$age` is a tiny number.. which will have almost no effect on the `test$age`.. isn't this a problem?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the ambiguity! I meant `train$age_scaled = ( train$age - mean(train$age) / sd(train$age)`, so you should scale both the test and train by the unscaled values in train.